# Keeping functions DRY when utilising multiple models

Tags: php, laravel-4

I currently have a bunch of models for an inventory system, and in one of the models is a function which handles adding variants to a product:

```
public function addVariant($options, $values = array())
{
    // Clone parent
    $variant = $this->replicate();

    // Update values for the cloned item
    if (count($values)) $this->updateValues($variant, $values);
    $variant->save();

    // Add options
    foreach ($options as $option) InventoryItemOption::addVariation($variant, $option);
}

private function updateValues($variant, $values)
{
    // Loop through the values and if the key exists, update the value
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) if (isset($variant->$key)) $variant->$key = $value;

    return $variant;
}
```

As part of addVariant, it adds the actual variations via `addVariation()` in `InventoryItemOption`:

```
public static function addVariation($item, $variation)
{
    $option = new InventoryItemOption;
    $option->item_id = $item->id;
    $option->option_id = $variation;
    $option->save();

    return $option;
}
```

How should this be handled in a dry way, not necessarily in this example, but any function which spans multiple models. Is this where a helper function should come in?

I want to validate the data passed after `updateValues()` and return a failure if it doesn't validate, but I also want to validate each of the variations being added via `addVariation()` are valid and exist in the database, I can do this by using a Validator however I am unsure whether one model should call another model at all in the first place.

I don't want to write multiple functions which do the same thing to add variations so it needs to be centralised somewhere, but as I am writing more functions I notice this cross model function calling is happening more and more.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Laravel makes it easy to keep things DRY, but requires a little creativity. Instead of your Model extending Eloquent, you can put a BaseModel in between:

```php
abstract class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    public function write($input, $key = 'id')
    {
        // Instantiate object
        if (! empty($input[$key]))
            $resource = $this->findOrFail($input[$key]);
        else
            $resource = $this;

        // Fill object with user input using Mass Assignment
        $resource->fill($input);

        // Save data to db
        if (! $resource->save())
            App::abort(500, 'Could not save resource');

        return $resource;
}

class Variant extends BaseModel {
}
```

Then on your Variant Model (or any other Model) you can set the `protected $fillable` attributes. To insert/update values on your Model, you only have to call the following from your controller:

```php
// Instantiate Model
$resource = new Variant;

// Write data to Model
$transaction = $resource->write($input);
```

In addition; you can use this same technique in regard to a `BaseController`, so your controllers will remain DRY also.